# Problema al procesar Imágenes subidas con Ajax y PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Estoy subiendo unas imágenes mediante Ajax y PHP, de comienzo quiero ver que se reciban bien las imágenes en PHP, así que idea una función simple, resulta ser que cuando subo por ejemplo imagen1, luego imagen2, ect, el script devuelvo lo pedido, pero si subo imagen1 y luego nuevamente imagen 1, no devuelve nada, será algún problema de cache o algo que quizás desconozca ?

Adjunto el Script JS

```
$('#imagenes').change(function(){
  cargar_imagenes();
})

function cargar_imagenes(){
    var input = document.getElementById('imagenes');
    var datos = new FormData();
    datos.append('action','fetch_data')

    // Iteramos sobre los archivos seleccionados y los agregamos al FormData
    var files = input.files;
    var archivos_descartados = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        if (files[i].size <= 2097152) { // 2MB en bytes
            // datos.append('imagenes['+i+']',files[i]);
            datos.append('imagenes[]', files[i], files[i].name);
        } else {
            archivos_descartados.push(files[i].name);
        }
    }
    
    $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo $dominioRaiz;?>logica/admin/web/subir_galeria.php",
        xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
        method: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType:false,
        data: datos,
        processData:false,              
        success:function(data){   
            alert(data.html1);
        }
    })

    // // Si se descartaron imágenes, mostramos un mensaje de error
    // if (archivos_descartados.length > 0) {
    //     var mensaje = 'Las siguientes imágenes superan el tamaño máximo de 2MB: ' + archivos_descartados.join(', ');
    //     alert(mensaje);
    // }


}
```

Script PHP

```
<?php
include dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../logica/conexion/conexion.php';
include dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../logica/conexion/rutas.php';
class ValidarNombreImagen {
    public function validar(){
        try {
            $con = new Conexion(DB_ADMIN);
            if (empty($_FILES['imagenes'])) {
                return 'error';
                exit();
            } else {
                $imagenes = $_FILES['imagenes']['tmp_name'];
                $input = 'imagenes'; 
                $path = '../../../images/';
                return $imagenes;
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
            die();
        }
    }           
}
$banners = new ValidarNombreImagen();
if(isset($_POST["action"])){
    $html1 = $banners->validar();    
    $data = array(
        "html1" => $html1
    );
    echo json_encode($data);    
}
?>
```

Comment: Las variables $input y $path para que las utilizas?, veo que se declara e inicializan pero no se usan, por otra parte, podrías tambien cambiar el nombre del archivo, para que siempre sea unico, esto lo puede hacer con $imagenes = sha1_file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']);

Comment: esas variables las pretendo usar más adelante para procesar y subir las imagenes, pero el problema creo que esta en JS, ya que en el script PHP puse un simple return 'Hola'; y al subir la imagen 1 vez se devuelve el hola, pero si subo la misma imagen nuevamente no se devuelve el hola